# Any python example working with PayPal IPN

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm having a problem working with Paypal's IPN. I've enabled IPN on my seller  accounts. Once payment goes thru, i get directed to the thank you page. But the backend that i specified in notify_url never actually gets "touch", that's why I can't update the db. :( please help me !!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to test your IPN URL following this instruction on [IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSimulator/)
first.

If the simulator errors out with 4XX/5XX, or your server access log indicates no "touch" from PayPal, you would probabebly have to troubleshoot on your server firewall/route settings, make sure it's not blacklisting PayPal domain or IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

here is the simplest Code in python I got working.
It is mostly from: https://flyingspaniel.blogspot.de/2014/12/do-frameworks-get-in-way.html with little changes by me.

though important: the IPN Verification did only work through sandbox NOT through the IPN Simulator when I tested!

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import cgi
import requests
import os; import json; import collections;
import urllib; from urllib import parse

inputraw =sys.stdin.read()

f = open('logfile','w')

print("content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n")

PAYPAL_URL = "https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"

formData ="cmd=_notify-validate&"+ parse.unquote(inputraw)

f.write(formData); f.write("\n") # write into file 1st data package from paypal

req = urllib.request.Request(PAYPAL_URL, formData.encode())
req.add_header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
status = str(response.read())

f.write(status) # write back into file what you received from paypal the 2nd time
f.write("\n")

if (not status == "b'VERIFIED'"):
        f.write("OH NO")
    #ERROR
else:
    #HERE WE WILL TRIGGER STUFF WITH THE DATA FROM PAYPAL
    f.write("OH YES")

f.write("\n")
f.close()
```